# Is it possible to get nativeElement reference directly from the template?

Tags: angular

I want to get native host element of the `mat-checkbox` so I can do `itemCheckbox.click()`. Now, `itemCheckbox` is a `MatCheckbox`. Can I get reference to the native element **directly in the template**?

```
  <mat-checkbox
                #itemCheckbox
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
  </mat-checkbox>
```

ideally I would imagine something like this

```
<our-component #item="ElementRef"></our-component>
```

PS. this is generic question. I know I can `itemCheckbox.toggle()` but the point is to get native element reference of the component in general. Also, I know I can `@ViewChild` given component and get native element from there, but that is not  the point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Comment: Unless I have to read between the line and read it as "no/cannot be done" than maybe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @viewChild() for that purpose like the following:

```
@ViewChild('itemCheckbox') private itemCheckbox: MatCheckbox;
```

keep that in mind to import `viewchild` and `MatCheckbox` like this:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material';
```

then you can access that in your code:

```
this.itemCheckbox.checked
```

Comment: This is offtopic - the question is how to get it directly - ergo without additional code in the component definition.